# Is there any way to kill a zombie process without reboot?

Tags: process, kill, zombie

Is there any way to kill a zombie process without reboot? Here is how it happened:

I want to download a 12GB file using torrent. After adding the .torrent file, transmission turned into a zombie process (I tried ktorrent too. Same behavior). Finally I could download the file using µTorrent but after closing the program, it turns into a zombie as well.

I tried using `kill`, `skill` and `pkill` with different options and `-9` signal but no success.

After reading some solutions on web, I found out killing the parent can kill the zombie. But killing wine didn't help either.

Is there another way?

**Edit:**

ps -o pid,ppid,stat,comm

```
PID  PPID STAT COMMAND
7121  2692 Ss   bash
7317  7121 R+   ps
```

pstree output:

```
init─┬─GoogleTalkPlugi───4*[{GoogleTalkPlug}]
 ├─NetworkManager─┬─dhclient
 │                └─{NetworkManager}
 ├─acpid
 ├─amarok───19*[{amarok}]
 ├─apache2───5*[apache2]
 ├─atd
 ├─avahi-daemon───avahi-daemon
 ├─bonobo-activati───{bonobo-activat}
 ├─clock-applet
 ├─console-kit-dae───63*[{console-kit-da}]
 ├─cron
 ├─cupsd
 ├─2*[dbus-daemon]
 ├─2*[dbus-launch]
 ├─desktopcouch-se───desktopcouch-se
 ├─firefox───run-mozilla.sh───firefox-bin─┬─plugin-containe───8*[{plugin-contain}]
 │                                        └─14*[{firefox-bin}]
 ├─gconfd-2
 ├─gdm-binary─┬─gdm-simple-slav─┬─Xorg
 │            │                 ├─gdm-session-wor─┬─gnome-session─┬─bluetooth-apple
 │            │                 │                 │               ├─compiz───sh───gtk-window-deco
 │            │                 │                 │               ├─fusion-icon
 │            │                 │                 │               ├─gdu-notificatio
 │            │                 │                 │               ├─gnome-panel───{gnome-panel}
 │            │                 │                 │               ├─gnome-power-man
 │            │                 │                 │               ├─gpg-agent
 │            │                 │                 │               ├─gwibber-service
 │            │                 │                 │               ├─nautilus
 │            │                 │                 │               ├─nm-applet
 │            │                 │                 │               ├─polkit-gnome-au
 │            │                 │                 │               ├─2*[python]
 │            │                 │                 │               ├─qstardict───{qstardict}
 │            │                 │                 │               ├─ssh-agent
 │            │                 │                 │               ├─tracker-applet
 │            │                 │                 │               ├─trackerd
 │            │                 │                 │               ├─wakoopa─┬─wakoopa
 │            │                 │                 │               │         └─3*[{wakoopa}]
 │            │                 │                 │               └─{gnome-session}
 │            │                 │                 └─{gdm-session-wo}
 │            │                 └─{gdm-simple-sla}
 │            └─{gdm-binary}
 ├─6*[getty]
 ├─gnome-keyring-d───2*[{gnome-keyring-}]
 ├─gnome-screensav
 ├─gnome-settings-
 ├─gnome-system-mo
 ├─gnome-terminal─┬─bash───ssh
 │                ├─bash───pstree
 │                ├─gnome-pty-helpe
 │                └─{gnome-terminal}
 ├─gvfs-afc-volume───{gvfs-afc-volum}
 ├─gvfs-fuse-daemo───3*[{gvfs-fuse-daem}]
 ├─gvfs-gdu-volume
 ├─gvfsd
 ├─gvfsd-burn
 ├─gvfsd-computer
 ├─gvfsd-metadata
 ├─gvfsd-trash
 ├─hald─┬─hald-runner─┬─hald-addon-acpi
 │      │             ├─hald-addon-cpuf
 │      │             ├─hald-addon-inpu
 │      │             └─hald-addon-stor
 │      └─{hald}
 ├─indicator-apple
 ├─indicator-me-se
 ├─indicator-sessi
 ├─irqbalance
 ├─kded4
 ├─kdeinit4─┬─kio_http_cache_
 │          └─klauncher
 ├─kglobalaccel
 ├─modem-manager
 ├─multiload-apple
 ├─mysqld───10*[{mysqld}]
 ├─named───10*[{named}]
 ├─nmbd
 ├─notification-ar
 ├─notify-osd
 ├─polkitd
 ├─pulseaudio─┬─gconf-helper
 │            └─2*[{pulseaudio}]
 ├─rsyslogd───2*[{rsyslogd}]
 ├─rtkit-daemon───2*[{rtkit-daemon}]
 ├─smbd───smbd
 ├─snmpd
 ├─sshd
 ├─timidity
 ├─trashapplet
 ├─udevd───2*[udevd]
 ├─udisks-daemon─┬─udisks-daemon
 │               └─{udisks-daemon}
 ├─upowerd
 ├─upstart-udev-br
 ├─utorrent.exe───{utorrent.exe}
 ├─vnstatd
 ├─winbindd───2*[winbindd]
 ├─wnck-applet
 ├─wpa_supplicant
 └─xinetd
```

System monitor and top show the zombie process is using resources:

[image]

[image]

**Edit 2:**
I think I found something. I tried to logout and saw this message:

[image]

Since other torrent clients have th same issue maybe it's something about file size.I'm using ubuntu 10.04 on ext4 partitions.Killing nautilus and sending SIGCHLD signal to it didn't work.

Comment: Can you add the output of `ps -o pid,ppid,stat,comm` and `pstree` to your question?

Comment: I am having the same problem here and after googling it seems that this occurs when having encrypted your home folder during the installation and choosing to download torrents bigger than 4gb. I haven't been able to find any other way than a reboot to get rid of the zombie process eating 99% cpu. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ecryptfs-utils/+bug/431975
seems to deal with this but nothing much seems to have been done in order to solve this :(

Comment: Also please read here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/48624/what-are-zombie-processes This will help solve many doubts.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I don't thing zombie process is much of a headache. A zombie process does not take up any resources. It is just that it has it's entry in the process table.

A Zombie process is not an orphan process, it does have a parent.

`kill`, `skill` `pkill` will not work since the process is already killed, just that it's entry has not been removed.

Zombie process can be killed by sending `SIGCHLD` signal to parent. 
I think the signal number of `SIGCHLD` is `17` or `18`

If this also fails, then you might want to kill the parent itself.

[From Wikipedia on SIGCHLD signal:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGCHLD)

> When a child process terminates before
>   the parent has called wait, the kernel
>   retains some information about the
>   process to enable its parent to call
>   wait later. Because the child is
>   still consuming system resources but
>   not executing it is known as a zombie
>   process.

---

**EDIT 1**: The system resources consumed is mostly the process table entry. If anyone knows if it consumes more than that - memory or CPU cycle, then please add an explanation. AFAIK it hardly takes up any significant system resources.

---

**[EDIT 2: Quoting from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process)**

> On Unix and Unix-like computer
>   operating systems, a zombie process or
>   defunct process is a process that has
>   completed execution but still has an
>   entry in the process table. This entry
>   is still needed to allow the process
>   that started the (now zombie) process
>   to read its exit status.

So the entry is kept so that the parent process can know the exit status because the moment the child exits, the parent is probably not in a state or not ready to read it's exit status.

---

**EDIT 3**

Till date I never experienced a zombie process taking 100% of the CPU. Seeing this for the first time.

Try doing a `killall utorrent.exe`

I can see that there are two instances of `utorrent.exe` and one of them is zombie. Probably the second one (child). killall should kill the parent since the child(zombie) cannot be killed.

---

**EDIT 4**

Looks like the killall did not work since it was giving TERM signal instead of KILL.

Try out `killall --signal=KILL utorrent.exe`

If this does not work then try killing the process selectivly.

Get the list of utorrent.exe process PID

> ps -e | grep -i utorrent

You should get two process like

```
xxxx ?        aa:bb:cc utorrent.exe defunct
yyyy ?        aa:bb:cc utorrent.exe
```

So the second one is the parent.
Kill it using

> kill -9 yyyy

**EDIT 5**

Please try finding the process's Parent Id by this bash command

> cat /proc/{defunctpid}/status | grep -i ppid

in your case is

> cat /proc/7298/status | grep -i ppid

If the output comes like

> PPid: 1

Then sadly I think you are out of luck. Process Id `1` belongs to init without which your system cannot run

Comment: You wrote `A zombie process does not take up any resources` and cited `the child is still consuming system resources ... it is known as a zombie process`.

Comment: Yeah. I updated the post to make it clear what I meant.

Comment: The zombie process takes one of my CPU cores entirely.The usage of that core is on 100%.So it's not only the process table entry.I will add additional information to the question.

Comment: This is the first time I am seeing a zombie process eating any resource. I also faced this problems, but never ever had this problem

Comment: I tried killall already.Didn't work.

Comment: Try `killall --signal=KILL utorrent.exe`

Comment: Nothing happened.

Comment: Try the `ps -e | grep -i utorrent` part of `Update 4`

Comment: Thanks for your great answer.But in answer of EDIT 4 I should say there is only 1 utorrent process: `17083 ?        00:20:45 utorrent.exe <defunct>` which can't be killed using -9.

Comment: You might want to check the output of `pstree` now and see if utorrent.exe is shown only one or two times now (given that you can see only one utorrent process)

Comment: Outout of `pstree |grep utorrent` is `|-utorrent.exe---{utorrent.exe}`.Updated pstree output is in the question.

Comment: Always use `pkill <process name>` instead of `killall <process name>`. Killall kills *everything* on some versions of unix (ie. Solaris) so it's good to avoid it.

Comment: I think that utorrent.exe process is now owned by init. The bigger question is when it is owned by init, why isn't init removing it?

Comment: Yeah.It's `PPid: 1`.Did you see the update in the question?

Comment: Noticing it now. Too bad. Not sure how this situation has to be handled

Comment: Too bad. No solution :(

Comment: A zombie using CPU may be running background threads. Try using `top -H` to display threads instead of processes in top.

Comment: This post is of multiple issues...

Comment: The major problem with defunct processes is that they keep using eventually used ports.

Comment: Zombie process will also trick the system to leaving any kind of resource open, files, sockets, tcp ports, etc.  This gets in the way of re-using those ports, unmounting volumes, delete files, etc.    When a system runs out of resources (CPU, Memory, and mostly disk space) it can leave processes in this Zombie defunct state.

Answer (score 11):

Using `kill` on the process itself is indeed ineffective, as the process is already dead; `kill` brings a live process to zombie state.

The parent process is responsible for picking up the exit code of the process; the process remains a zombie until this is done. The `init` process will pick up the exit code of any process and throw it away, so it is the "last-resort" parent that will clean up any zombie that is a direct descendant.

Killing the parent of the zombie process is usually effective because the zombie process then reverts to `init` as its parent as soon as the parent process is gone (i.e. killing the parent has turned that process into a zombie, and the grandparent has read the parent's exit code, so the parent is truly gone). A zombie can be parent to a zombie, so merely killing the parent is not sufficient, it also needs to be collected by another process itself.

Note that processes are never responsible for cleaning up their grandchildren -- they always revert to process 1 as parent (which is why daemon authors sometimes use a double fork() and terminate the process in the middle to fully disassociate the child process from the invoking shell)

The reason why killing `wine` probably isn't effective is because it wasn't really the parent of the zombie process; rather, the "utorrent.exe" that is a direct descendant of init is. This process however is still running normally, just neglecting its duties.

Comment: Thanks for information.But what's the solution?

Comment: Killing the *real* parent process, i.e. the one that `ps waux` lists in the `PPID` column for the zombie.

Comment: As you can see in the pstree output "utorrent.exe" doesn't have any parent.

Comment: There are two processes with that name, where one is the child of the other. I suspect the zombie is the child, which would make the parent "utorrent.exe" process responsible for cleanup; if you kill that process, then init will clean up the parent, after which the child is reattached to init and immediately cleaned up as well.

Comment: killall didn't work in that case.I started µTorrent now and it doesn't have any parent or child, but cannot be killed yet.pstree output is updated.

Comment: Sorry for mistake.It's the same situation but kill all doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Much easier way than killall, -9, etc:

1)Use qBitorrent instead instead of the console uTorrent (I'm waiting for a GUI version as well and qBitorrent is essentially it).

2)If you are using 11.04 or above, hit alt+f2 (opens a special commands window), type xkill and your mouse is now an x. Click on the program you want to close (UI = process ID) and it will kill it for you.

Advanced tip: bind a keyboard shortcut for "xkill" like I have on my G15 macro keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

In my case when wine hangs and i can not kill the Zombie child with a shotgun i would do:

`wineserver -k` then i would kill the "Son of the Process" `killall -9 Oblivion.exe` (For example)

For what i understand wineserver sends a signal to all its Zombie Childs that they are all going to die (Because of the shotgun you know) but sometimes a child thinks by itself and wants to take the world by storm. So i do the additional `killall -9` or the `kill -9` with the id of the process.

Comment: It didn't work either.Besides transmission and ktorrent have the same problem and they have nothing to do with wine.

Comment: I was mentioning the part about using utorrent with wine being wine the parent and utorrent the child. Anyway did you try to send a signal to the parent letting it know that its child is a zombie (Something no parent is ready for). For example: `kill -s SIGCHLD ppid`

Comment: Also what type of hardware do you have so it might help finding out how a zombie can use resources to the max.

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work either.

Comment: My processor is core i7 860.

Comment: Interesting. Can you give me a step by step guide on how to create the problem your are facing. I have a friend who also has an i7 860 so i can test the problem there.

Comment: I'm trying to download this torrent: http://www.kickasstorrents.com/the-fast-and-the-furious-tokyo-drift-bdrip-1080p-h264-ita-eng-ac3-dts-sub-tntvillage-t4777876.html using utorrent.After a few minutes of download closing utorrent does not kill the process.

Comment: Using Transmission can do the same too.But now I see it doesn't happen every time.Sometimes it turns into zombie and sometimes it doesn't.Also this time transmission doesn't use my processor (last time it did).But but utorrent use resources when it turns into zombie.

Comment: That is the case -> `cat /proc/<PID>/status | grep -i ppid`  --->> if the output comes like `PPid: 1`  ---->> "Then sadly I think you are out of luck. Process Id 1 belongs to init without which your system cannot run" 

No Solution. Only rebooting the box.  ^_~

Answer (score -4):

My guess is that you're using an SSD.

When adding large torrents to a torrent client, the "placeholder" files of the torrent you are downloading are actually created on disk, but are empty until gradually filled during the download process.

With a normal hard disk, the disk is the bottleneck, and you won't notice a performance issue with the rest of your desktop.

When using an SSD however, the CPU is the bottleneck, and the application appears to have crashed (goes gray). If you leave it for a while, it will recover and all will be well. This has been my experience since switching to an SSD.

With regard to killing processes, others have provided better advice than I can - using the KILL signal usually works, but I have had the odd one that required a restart over the years.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using a normal hard disk.

Comment: *"When using an SSD however, the CPU is the bottleneck, and the application appears to have crashed (goes gray). If you leave it for a while, it will recover and all will be well."* In that situation, the process is not a zombie. Zombie processes and processes in [uninterruptible sleep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninterruptible_sleep#Uninterruptible_sleep) are not the same thing. A zombie process truly is not running anymore, does not take up resources (except a single entry in the process table), and cannot ever come back to life.