# Zombie process: sd_cicero, Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: lightdm, upstart, process, kill, zombie

When I followed the instructions in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/111422/how-to-find-zombie-process) to find zombie processes, I found this process `Z    Jan02   0:00 [sd_cicero] <defunct>`. When I try to find its parent process, I get this:
`systemd(1)───lightdm(1305)───lightdm(1524)───upstart(1797)───sd_cicero(4795)───sd_cicero(4796)`

What is this process, and why could it have become a zombie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the process forked itself and the child has exited, but the parent is not correctly reaping the child.  If this situation persists, then this is a bug in the program that you should report.